# Send data to server from client in python

Tags: python, sockets

```
import socket
import os
import msvcrt
import time

def timeInput(text="",e="",timeFin=0.01):
    result=[]
    done=time.time() +timeFin
    print(text,end=e)
    while 1:
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            echo=msvcrt.getch().decode('ASCII')
            result.append(echo)
            time.sleep(0.1)
        else:
            if time.time() > done:
                st=""
                for i in result:
                    st=st+str(i)
                st=st.replace("`b","")
                return st



#username=("Username? ")

#x, y, width, height, username, map position, list position

try:
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect(('10.0.0.7', 25565))
    while 1:
        #data = client_socket.recv(512)
        #key=timeInput()

        #code="player,100,200,30,30,player2,0,1"
        code="chat,hi,Marc"
        client_socket.send(bytes(code,"UTF-8"))

except Exception as e:
    print("ERROR: "+str(e))
```

for some reason when I try connecting to my server in python, it connects properly but it won't continuously send  `chat,hi,Marc` to the server. I have no clue why this is not working, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

socket.send() does not guarantee that all bytes have been sent (or, better said, that all bytes have been copied to the outgoing buffer). send() blocks until at least one character can be sent.

You are probably filling the out buffer fast because of the loop, and then adding some parts of the message, then blocking until some buffer space is released.

So, you need to read the result of send(). If it is > 0, that's how many bytes you've sent, so you have to send() again the remaining part. If send() returns <= 0, connection is closed and you should exit the loop.